# Windows Service, VPN, MSAccess

Tags: c#, ms-access, windows-services, odbc, vpn

I wrote Windows Service in C# to get data from Excel and Access tables. Everything works fine until I try to get data from remote database through VPN connection:

```
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The Microsoft Access database 
engine cannot open or write to the file '(unknown)'. It is already opened exclusively 
by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.
```

Driver is ODBC.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the error message. It's not very helpful but is completely accurate.

It's likely that your service is running as a user that does not have the needed permissions to the file, or that the ODBC connection is supplying the credentials and they are wrong or missing.

You can debug your service by opening the project in Visual Studio and selecting Debug->Attach To Process and selecting your service. You can then step through it and see exactly what is failing and what login credentials are being used when it happens.

Note that the default credentials for Windows Services do not have rights to anything on other machines, so that would be a good place to start.

If you can open it across the VPN from MS Access, but not your service, that narrows it down quite a bit.